# nodemailer 2.x configuration for Office 365 direct send

Tags: office365, nodemailer

I'm using nodemailer v2.4.2 with node.js v4.4.7 and I want to send emails from my server via my Office 365 SMTP mail server. I'm using the smtpTransport v2.5.0 with this configuration:

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
  host: 'smtp.office365.com',
  port: 25, // have tried 465
  secureConnection: secure,
  auth: {
    user: username,
    pass: password
  },
  tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false // don't verify certificates
  },
  ignoreTLS: false // don't turn off STARTTLS support
}));
```

I've tried specifying an `authMethod` of `LOGIN` and `PLAIN` but neither make any difference.  When I try and send an email I get an error:

```
[Error: Invalid login: 504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type]
code: 'EAUTH',
response: '504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type',
responseCode: 504
```

Does anyone have any idea on what authorization type is expected by Office 365 and whether I need to specify any different settings in the nodemailer setup?

Comment: plz, mark correct answer if solved your question!!

Answer (score 37):

This works for me:

```
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.office365.com', // Office 365 server
        port: 587,     // secure SMTP
        secure: false, // false for TLS - as a boolean not string - but the default is false so just remove this completely
        auth: {
            user: username,
            pass: password
        },
        tls: {
            ciphers: 'SSLv3'
        }
    });
```

You may like to add:

```
    requireTLS: true
```

Comment: This works, and the explanations were very helpful. thanks

Comment: `secure:false` and adding `requireTLS: true` works for me, thankyou

Comment: requireTLS: true was not required for. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                  host: "smtpout.secureserver.net",
                  port: 587,
                  secureConnection: false,
                  secure: false,
                  requireTLS: true,
                  auth: {
                    user: emailUsr,
                    pass: emailPass
                  },
                  tls: {
                    rejectUnauthorized: false
                  }
                });
```

You can try with this configuration

Answer (score 1):

A very late answer but if you are using a shared mailbox from Office365, you won't be able to authenticate via SMTP. I also got this error and then realized this.

Refer [Can Office365 shared mailbox use SMTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41600490/can-office365-shared-mailbox-use-smtp) for information on this.

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario I had to make sure the email field `From` was using the same email address I used for the mailbox login - in the `options` object at: `auth.user`.

This way, provided I was using the TLS details for `STARTTLS` e.g. `auth.user.secure: false`, `requireTLS: true` and `tls.ciphers: 'SSLv3'`, I managed to send an email with Nodemailer.

Answer (score 0):

```
let testAccount = await nodemailer.createTestAccount();
      let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: "Outlook365",
        host: 'smtp.office365.com',
        port: '587',
        tls: {
          ciphers:'SSLv3',
          rejectUnauthorized: false 
        },
        auth: {
            user: "",
            pass: ""
        }
      });
```

You can use the office 365/outlook configuration with node-mailer to send mail using outlook account –

Comment: You can use the office 365/outlook configuration with node-mailer to send mail using outlook account